# Как установить иконку для сайта?

Tags: html, icon

Почему-то в разделе `head` HTML-документа написал:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon/favicon.ico">`

Разместил в папке файл "`favicon.ico`", но всё равно иконка не отображается!

Кто-нибудь, подскажите, в чём причина, пожалуйста.

Comment: Отслеживайте сетевые запросы отладчиком. Там будет видно в чем ошибка.

Comment: Браузер у вас какой?

Comment: https://habr.com/en/post/330584/

Answer (score 2):

Ну, во-первых, надо убедиться, что icon/favicon.ico - верный путь до иконки. Ну если все в порядке, то значит браузер виноват, т.е. кэш. Бывало такое. Но попробуй обмануть, в обоих случаях помогает, так как код страницы меняется.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

или так (задать абсолютный путь)

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/icon/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас какой сервер? Если апач, то кинте favicon.ico в корень сайта и будет вам счастье.

Comment: У меня denwer стоит, так я когда иконку загрузил, сколько не бился, так и не появилась.  
Появилась через дня три - неделю... Вот так вот, время - лучший помощник)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так: 
`<link rel="icon" href="./icon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

Comment: Как писал комментатор снизу: "Очччень своевременный ответ".

Answer (score 0):

В настоящее время, что бы просто вставить иконку, достаточно прописать как уже выше сказали 1 строчку и закинуть файл на сервер. Но есть множество сценариев, при которых обычная фавиконка не решает поставленные задачи, в дополнение к ответам, могу порекомендовать сервис, который с легкостью подготовит ваше изображение под все популярные платформы.

https://realfavicongenerator.net/

Answer (score -1):

Я всегда вставляю следующим образом (обычно ложу в корень сайта, туда же куда и index.html или index.php:

```
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon"         type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"    type="image/x-icon" />
```

Многие поисковики и браузеры, сами ищут эту иконку в корне сайта по имени favicon

В вашем случае код должен быть таким (если вы указываете относительный путь):

```
<link href="icon/favicon.ico" rel="icon"        type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="icon/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"   type="image/x-icon" />
```

Да я использую две строки с разными rel="" атрибутами. Так сложилось исторически из-за браузеров и их "перетягиваний одеяла"

А еще иконка может не показываться, если у неё неверно указан формат. Например сделать иконку в ФШ и сохранить её как .ico почему то не всегда срабатывает. Я делаю иконки в ФШ, сохраняю как jpg а потом программой IcoFX конвертирую их в .ico уже несколько лет так и все отлично работает.

Answer (score -3):

У меня тоже такая проблема была. Короче кидаешь иконку в корень сайта(Не знаю надо или нет но у меня так), прописываешь (С такими скобками< > незнаю как их поставить   link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"
ТЕПЕРЬ!
Перезагружаешь сервер свой. У меня Опен Сервер там все просто у тебя не знаю как

Comment: Очччень своевременный ответ!